# bootstrap and custom css overlaps, not functioning together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage where I have to display bullet points on the screen as well as some custom css designs.It displays either one.Here is a snippet below,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Background.css">
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">          </script>
.
.
.
.
After the above somewhere in body section , I have to display the below,
<ul>
For Broker-Dealers this includes but is not limited to:
<li>AML testing and reviews</li></ul>
```

Now the problem is , if in head section the below css is there  then "ul" part is not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Background.css">
```

but I need both css. Appreciate any suggestion .

Regards,
Sharmistha

Answer (score 0):

add inside Background.css file, the code word important with !

```
someSelector {some-rule: value !important; }
```